# How to connect to SAP BO universe via Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, business-objects, sap-bw

Our enterprise management database is housed in Business Objects Universes. I'm looking for our Power BI analysts to create Power BI reports by connecting to universes.

This link says such a connector was available: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/power-bi-connectivity-to-sap-businessobjects-bi-now-generally-available/

It also says it is no longer available:

> Update May 2016: SAP BO connectivity is no longer available. Microsoft
> Power BI has new SAP BW and SAP HANA connectors. Learn more about
> these connectors.

Does this mean that I can use the SAP BW and/or SAP HANA connectors to connect to the SAP BO universe? or is connectivity to universe not possible anymore?

The following link from Power BI Ideas says that the connector was removed altogether: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=8903cb67-e1df-4014-8b36-eaae3c4ba00c

> Administrator on 12/7/2020 10:45:41 PM Unfortunately, the Business
> Objects connector was removed due to a number of reasons.

Following are similar ideas but there is no response:

- https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=d6b2decd-89e0-480a-ab62-c08a809db281
- https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=fd98c963-549d-eb11-89ee-281878bda47d
- https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=4cc55370-2291-4b90-9606-957f5727108f

How to connect to SAP BO universe via Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

> How to connect to SAP BO universe via Power BI?

Either through a custom connector, an ODBC connector, or if BO supports standard web protocols.  Looks like CData has an [ODBC driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/sapbusinessobjectsbi/).

But the recommended approach create new "semantic layer" using Power BI Datasets that load the same data and bypass BO.